# Concat fields into one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this query below:

```
var query = {
    $and:
    [
        {
            uf:
            {
                $exists: true,
                $ne: ""
            }
        },
        {
            municipio:
            {
                $exists: true,
                $ne: ""
            }
        },
        {
            $or:
                [
                    {
                        email:
                        {
                            $exists: true,
                            $ne: ""
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        telefone:
                        {
                            $exists: true,
                            $ne: ""
                        }
                    }
                ]
        },
    ]
}

var mod = {
    atividade_principal: 1,
    $concat: [
        "$logradouro", ", ", "$numero", " - ", "$bairro", ", ", "$municipio", " - ", "$uf", ", ", "$cep",
    ],
    telefone: 1,
    email: 1,
    qsa: 1,
    nome: 1,
    natureza_juridica: 1,
    tipo: 1
}

db.empresas.find(query, mod).limit(1000);
```

and I want to concat this line:

```
$concat: [
    "$logradouro", ", ", "$numero", " - ", "$bairro", ", ", "$municipio", " - ", "$uf", ", ", "$cep",
]
```

But as what i was seeing that it is not allowed in find() function, but I have no idea how to use aggregate to do that, because aggregate framework is showing that what it allows is get many documents and transform them into a one document grouping all the other documents, if I am wrong, please clarify me.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such difference between `find` and `aggregate` function. Aggregation is just used to reshape the data nothing else. And there are some operators available to reshape that data in aggregate function.

In find query first parameter is for filter and the second one is for projection and the same role [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) do here in aggregation

```
const query = {
  "$and": [
    { "uf": { "$exists": true, "$ne": "" } },
    { "municipio": { "$exists": true, "$ne": "" }},
    {
      "$or": [
        { "email": { "$exists": true, "$ne": "" }},
        { "telefone": { "$exists": true, "$ne": "" }}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const projection = {
  "atividade_principal": 1,
  "concatinatedField": { "$concat": ["$logradouro", ", ", "$numero", " - ", "$bairro", ", ", "$municipio", " - ", "$uf", ",", "$cep"] },
  "telefone": 1,
  "email": 1,
  "qsa": 1,
  "nome": 1,
  "natureza_juridica": 1,
  "tipo": 1
}

db.empresas.aggregate([
  { "$match": query },
  { "$limit": 1000 },
  { "$project": projection }
])
```